# Borderless windows form with Windows 7 dragging enhancements

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7

In Windows 7, you can drag a typical window to the top of your screen and you'll see an outline of the window maximized. If you let go, Windows will maximize the form. Likewise, you can take an already maximized window and "pull" it down to restore it to the normal windowstate. I'd like to leverage these enhancements in a borderless form within my C# WinForms app.

My form is borderless so I can create a custom titlebar and minimize/maximize/close buttons. I can get my form to move by dragging the titlebar but I don't know how to plug into the Windows 7 enhancements that give me the maximize outline or the "pull down" feature.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this in Delphi 7, years ago.

1) Form - OnCLick - capture mouse position on entire screen (maybe this link will help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx), save information about button pressed in private variable (example: buttonPressed = true)
2) Form - OnMouseMove - according to new mouse position, move your window
3) Form - OnMouseUp - buttonPressed = false. If cursor coordinates are in top of screen (x[0..screenW] y[0..10] ) --> maximize.

Just a hint, maybe it will help you.